# Is there a Google Image Search API?

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-image-search, pdf-scraping

I'm searching for an API or a program (preferably **Python** and open-source) which lets me download the first **n** pictures of a Google Image Search for let's say **bicycles**. It would also be helpful if it could download the first **n** .pdf files from a normal search. Since not all pictures and .pdf files are found on Google and since there are many other search engines, a program which could also scrape results from **Yahoo** or **Bing** would be very convenient. Are there any such programs or is there an API from Google which lets me do more than 100 searches a day?

***edit***: People passing by may want to look at my attempt of programming such a scraper [here](https://github.com/stendarr/searchengine-imagescraper)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119842/google-image-search-api?rq=1

Comment: @TungD.Nguyen Can I embed this API into a Python program? and also this API is deprecated

Comment: you dont need to use google image search api   i wrote code using python to download  full resolution images from google  given a querry  http://stackoverflow.com/a/28487500/2875380

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this [post](http://searchengineland.com/google-to-shut-several-search-apis-in-february-240413), all Google Search APIs have been deprecated.

However, [GoogleScraper, an open-source library](https://github.com/NikolaiT/GoogleScraper) can help you achieve what you intend achieving.

If want to go barebones, and implement this yourself, BeautifulSoup is a very nice library to work with.